# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method when using World.setBlock() in MC Forge

Tags: java

**First of all, I know this question has been beaten to death, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the answers in my code.**

Now, I'm trying to make a Minecraft mod where I set a block to a location of an entity using World.setBlock()

The issue is, once I put all of my arguments in, eclipse says that it cannot make a static reference to the non-static method.

I understand that I am supposed to make an instance of the non-static method in my class however I can't seem to figure out how to make this work.

Here is my code:

```
package noahc3.MaterialBlobs;

import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.projectile.EntityThrowable;
import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import net.minecraft.util.MovingObjectPosition;
import net.minecraft.util.MovingObjectPosition.MovingObjectType;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

public class EntityDirtBlob extends EntityThrowable 
{
    World world = new World();

    //The above line is the part I can't figure out how to do correctly.

    public EntityDirtBlob(World par1World, double par2, double par4, double par6)
    {
    super(par1World, par2, par4, par6);
    }
    public EntityDirtBlob(World par1World, EntityLivingBase par2EntityLivingBase)
    {
    super(par1World, par2EntityLivingBase);
    }
    public EntityDirtBlob(World par1World)
    {
    super(par1World);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onImpact(MovingObjectPosition mop)
    {
        if(mop.typeOfHit == MovingObjectType.BLOCK)
        {
        switch(mop.sideHit)
        {
        case 0: //BOTTOM
        mop.blockY--;
        break;
        case 1: //TOP
        mop.blockY++;
        break;
        case 2: //EAST
        mop.blockZ--;
        break;
        case 3: //WEST
        mop.blockZ++;
        break;
        case 4: //NORTH
        mop.blockX--;
        break;
        case 5: //SOUTH
        mop.blockX++;
        break;
        }
        World.setBlock(mop.blockX, mop.blockY, mop.blockZ, Blocks.dirt)

        //The above line is where eclipse complains that it cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
        }
        if (!this.worldObj.isRemote)
        {
        this.setDead();
        }
     System.out.println("Entity landed!");
    }
}
```

I commented in where I couldn't figure out how to solve the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: setBlock isnt a static method. See below answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `World.setBlock` with `world.setBlock`.

The first references the `World` class and the second references the instance of `World` that you created.

Comment: world.setBlock doesn't seem to work, just says can't resolve world.

Comment: Is the code above exactly the code that you have in your editor? If you change to `world`, then the code above should compile. `world` is a field on the class and should be available in any non-static method of the class. The error that you are describing implies that you are working with something slightly different.  I'd suggest commenting out lines until you isolate the problem.

Comment: I've changed World.setBlock(mop.blockX, mop.blockY...) to world.setBlock(mop.blockX...). The full code of the class is [here](http://pastebin.com/zYuUr4YJ)

I'm really not sure what could be different from what I gave you...

Comment: In your snippet, you commented out the field declaration for the `world` variable. Now, change `world setBlock() = new world.setBlock();` to `World world = new World();` and uncomment it.